/Fo Command Does Not Output Object When Compiling C++ std Module
Context
I am using Visual Studio 2022 v17.10.4
So I am attempting to make a script to make compiling C++ programs easier for me using the Visual Studio 2022 compiler. I found a textbook about programming using C++ written by Bjarne Stroustrup, the creator of C++, and the very first program depicted doesn't work because the C++ standard is too new for Visual Studio's compiler to understand what import std; means without manually linking the compiled std object.
I have the script set up and everything, but I am having trouble compiling the std.ixx file to create the std module so the compiler will understand what import std; means.
The Problem
For further context on compiling the C++ std Module using Visual Studio 2022's compiler, see this; it's the same tutorial I was attempting to follow.
I set up the environment using "Z:\Applications\Visual Studio IDE\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86 as they imply in the tutorial.
Attempting to debug the problem, I write into the command window:
cl /std:c++latest /EHsc /nologo /W4 /c "Z:\Applications\Visual Studio IDE\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\modules\std.ixx" /Fo:"Z:\Documents\GitHub\VS-CompileForMe" /ifcOutput"Z:\Documents\GitHub\VS-CompileForMe"

For some reason, I can find the output ifc std.ifc in the specified directory, but the output object std.obj is nowhere to be found. The command window after running the command simply reads:
std.ixx


and that's it.
Unecessary workaround
What I found is that I can cd /d to the directory Z:\Documents\GitHub\VS-CompileForMe, and if I omit the switch /Fo:"Z:\Documents\GitHub\VS-CompileForMe" then I can actually find the std.obj file.
Keep in mind I also tried running the x86 Native Tools command prompt from the search bar as they described in the tutorial and the same problem occurred.
The Question
Does anyone know why this might be? Is this a compiler bug? Have I written something incorrectly?

I don't understand what you want to accomplish and why you compile obj. Nowhere in the linked tutorial examples /Fo is mentioned.

Also, "Is this a compiler bug?". No. :-)  About once every 10 years it is a compiler bug, at all other times it is your own fault.  I think here the problem is that you want to automate the building yourself, when you already have the option to use the Visual Studio IDE. It will do all the work at a click of a button! Why not use that? (You can learn "how it really works" later).

"As an aside", part 2.  I have used Visual Studio since version 1.0, and have never typed in a /Fo command. That's why I think you, as a beginner, is trying this from the wrong end. You should focus on C++ the language, not on how to type in half a mile of compiler commands. Because as a developer, that is not what you do, you use a tool to do it for you.

@bop the problem of "at a click of a button" means constantly excluding cpp files just because I want to create small scripts and not a large project. Visual Studio doesn't support creating one-off scripts (at least as far as I am aware). I working on creating a batch script to make it easier to compile example cpp scripts so that I don't have to play song-and-dance with manually excluding and including cpp files in the IDE. Visual Studio expects one and only one main function.

@3CxEZiVlQ the command outputs both std.ifc and std.obj and you must have the std.obj file on standby so that you can link it to programs that use the statement import std;. Without std.obj you can't link the std module and your program will fail to compile if you attempt to import std.

Sure, so I have one quick_test project set up with an empty main function. Then I can just cut-and-paste any code snippet I want to test and click the "Compile"-button. Takes about 2 seconds. :-)

@bop I guess I could do that, but I need a way to save these scripts. I'm not necessarily looking to test small snippets, but write out examples as they come up in the textbook and save them for later (either for reference or to just have it). There's a whole lot of finagling I already did with Batch just to create a working script, so at least I got to learn some Batch, as archaic as it is. The script I made lets me compile outside the IDE just as easily as inside the IDE, without having to work with copy-pasting nor including/excluding files.

Have you considered changing /ifcOutput" to /ifcOutput "?

@Compo the /ifOutput switch isn't the problem, but I tried it regardless just in case of something and still the same problem

I never said it was your reported problem, @Xbox360. I was simply telling you to use the documented syntax. You included a space correctly after /c, and correctly excluded one when the option terminated with a colon. There is just no need to hope that excluding one here is wise, especially given that you're questioning the results of a command using multiple options.

/Fo is not a command, it's a parameter/flag/argument

I use the tool
Visual Studio IDE\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86

/Fo sets the name of the object file
From the cmd in question, the output folder is  Z:\Documents\GitHub, output object is VS-CompileForMe.obj
/Fo:"Z:\Documents\GitHub\VS-CompileForMe"

I used the following command and am able to find the obj and ifc files:
cl /std:c++latest /EHsc /nologo /W4 /c "%VCToolsInstallDir%\modules\std.ixx" /Fo:"...OutputFolder\\" /ifcOutput"...OutputFolder"  

\\ is used in  ...OutputFolder\\
Check the usage of  /Fo:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fo-object-file-name?view=msvc-170#example

@Xbox 360 Is there any update?
